# How to save the state of an array every n time steps?

Tags: python, numpy, simulation

Reposting here since physics stack exchange said it belongs here. I am doing a simple test particle simulation of the orbits of 8 planets around the sun. I need to optimize the code a bit. My stored position and velocity arrays are very large (if I put a large t_end) and I would like to save the pos and vel every n=10000 (for example) time steps instead of storing all the positions and velocities. I tried different methods but couldn't really solve the problem. I want to do it such that the pos and vel arrays are overwritten and not stored for every time step, but only stored for every n=10000 time steps. So, maybe instead of storing them in arrays, I want to write the pos and vel to a file and update the file after every n steps so as to add the new values in a new row/line.

My current code is just me creating a new array where I store the values every n steps.

I know this might affect my current orbit plot, any inputs are appreciated but this is just a structure for a much more complex simulation later, where I won't need every value from my simulation.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Constants
M_Sun = 1.989e30 #Solar Mass
G = 6.67430e-11  # m^3 kg^(-1) s^(-2)
yr = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 #1 year in seconds

# Number of particles
num_particles = 8

# Initial conditions for the particles (m and m/s)
initial_pos = np.array([
    [57.9e9, 0, 0], #Mercury
    [108.2e9, 0, 0], #Venus
    [149.6e9, 0, 0], #Earth
    [228e9, 0, 0], #Mars
    [778.5e9, 0, 0], #Jupiter
    [1432e9, 0, 0], #Saturn
    [2867e9, 0, 0], #Uranus
    [4515e9, 0, 0] #Neptune
])

initial_vel = np.array([
    [0, 47400, 0],
    [0, 35000, 0],
    [0, 29800, 0],
    [0, 24100, 0],
    [0, 13100, 0],
    [0, 9700, 0],
    [0, 6800, 0],
    [0, 5400, 0]
])

# Steps
t_end = 0.004 * yr #Total time of integration
dt_constant = 0.1
intervals = 10000 #Number of outputs of pos and vel to be saved


# Arrays to store pos and vel
pos = np.zeros((num_particles, int(t_end), 3))
vel = np.zeros((num_particles, int(t_end), 3))

# Leapfrog Integration (2nd Order)
pos[:, 0] = initial_pos
vel[:, 0] = initial_vel
saved_pos = []
saved_vel = []


t = 1
counter = 0

while t < int(t_end):
    r = np.linalg.norm(pos[:, t - 1], axis=1)
    acc = -G * M_Sun / r[:, np.newaxis]**3 * pos[:, t - 1] #np.newaxis for broadcasting with pos[:, i-1]

    # Calculate the time step for the current particle
    current_dt = dt_constant * np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(pos[:, t - 1], axis=1)**3 / (G * M_Sun))
    min_dt = np.min(current_dt)  # Use the minimum time step for all particles

    half_vel = vel[:, t - 1] + 0.5 * acc * min_dt
    pos[:, t] = pos[:, t - 1] + half_vel * min_dt

    # Recalculate acceleration with the new position
    r = np.linalg.norm(pos[:, t], axis=1)
    acc = -G * M_Sun / r[:, np.newaxis]**3 * pos[:, t] #np.newaxis for broadcasting with pos[:, i-1]
    vel[:, t] = half_vel + 0.5 * acc * min_dt
    
    t += 1
    counter += 1

    # Save the pos and vel here
    if counter % intervals == 0:
        saved_pos.append(pos[:,t].copy())
        saved_vel.append(vel[:,t].copy())

saved_pos = np.array(saved_pos)
saved_vel = np.array(saved_vel)

# Orbit Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(0, 0, 0, color='yellow', marker='o', s=50, label='Sun')

for particle in range(num_particles):
    x_particle = pos[particle, :, 0]
    y_particle = pos[particle, :, 1]
    z_particle = pos[particle, :, 2]
    ax.plot(x_particle, y_particle, z_particle, label=f'Particle {particle + 1} Orbit (km)')

ax.set_xlabel('X (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (km)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z (km)')
ax.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1))
ax.set_title('Orbits of Planets around Sun (km)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store" ? Like, in memory ? Or in disk ?

Comment: Not sure if I know exactly the difference but I don't want the arrays to store every value in memory. And every nth value in a file for pos and vel.

Comment: Then just count the iterations. Use an "if" statement : if iteration can be divided by 10 000 without remainder (modulo) ex : if iteration % 10000 == 0 then store the values in a data structure.

Comment: Ok I tried it and I have updated my question with the new code. But when I print the arrays, I get only 0 values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bluebee09r If you're revising your question, put the revision into the question itself rather than in a comment. Also, be aware that changing to an entirely different question after getting a response to the original is known as "moving the goalposts", and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will keep that in mind, new to posting here :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original code has been altered in response to Loïc Ribere's comment. That edit negates the content of the question as currently worded. Additionally, the author has now asked a different question using a comment but has not revised the wording of the original question, so it is no longer self-contained/self-consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to understand why this happens if you step through your program in a debugger. If you aren't familiar with a debugger, I highly recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Add a breakpoint at the `saved_pos.append(pos[:,t].copy())` line, and inspect what's being appended to the `saved_pos` array. Since `counter` lags `t` by 1, you have:

- `counter` is `10000`, which activates the `if` condition
- `t` is `10001`

However, you haven't yet done anything to `pos[:, t]`, which is why it is still zeros and that gets appended to the `saved_pos`.

You want to either append `pos[:, counter]` to the list, or check `if t % intervals == 1` (since `t` starts at 1)

Or, increment `t` *after* you've appended that array to the list

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Changing to 'pos[:, counter]' worked. Now I should be able to just write the saved_pos and saved_vel to a file.